# Flask-Migrate: column addition / removal apparently undetected, tables recreated instead

Tags: python, flask, alembic, flask-migrate

I'm using Flask-Migrate in a Flask application with a Postgresql backend. The problem is that after making a change to my models, say a column addition or removal, in any revision or migration that I have tried I always get results along the lines of

```
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table u'foo'
```

and every script in `migrations/versions` contains code for the **creation** of tables, e.g.

```
def upgrade():
    ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('foo',
    ...
    )
    ### end Alembic commands ###
```

I was expecting something like

```
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added column u'foo.name'
```

and

```
def upgrade():
        ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
        op.add_column('foo', sa.Column('name', ...
        )
        ### end Alembic commands ###
```

I'm following the instructions given in this [blog](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/flask-migrate-alembic-database-migration-wrapper-for-flask). The relevant settings are as follows:

```
    ### __init__.py
    import ...
    from flask.ext.script import Manager
    from flask.ext.migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('config')
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    db.metadata.schema = app.config['DB_SCHEMA']
    migrate = Migrate(app, db)
    manager = Manager(app)
    manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)
    ...
    import myapp.models

    ###  models.py
    from myapp import db

    class Foo(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
```

I followed some of the suggestions given in these questions: 
([Alembic/Flask-migrate doesn't recognise database structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482817/alembic-flask-migrate-doesnt-recognise-database-structure)) and ([No changes detected in Alembic autogeneration of migrations with Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409724/no-changes-detected-in-alembic-autogeneration-of-migrations-with-flask-sqlalchem)) with no luck whatsoever.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**Solved**

I just discovered the problem. I like to use DB schemas, and I was doing this

```
    db.metadata.schema = app.config['DB_SCHEMA']
```

It seems `alembic` somehow is not aware of the inherent *scope* of the schema and therefore it **recreates** the tables all the time. Sort of: there is no table `foo` - in the outermost, global 'schema' or scope - so I have to `create` that table. This was happening even after the *very first migration* correctly created the table. Of course, execution of a second migration unsurprisingly produced

```
    sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) relation "foo" already exists
```

I just dropped the above declaration and now I see the changes coming out properly.

```
    INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added column 'foo.name'
```

I don't know if I have to do something special to support schemes. Perhaps this is just an unsupported feature.

Comment: Does table "foo" exist in your database when you generate the migration? It seems the table does not exist.

Comment: No, I'm starting with an empty DB. Actually I'm following the blog on the 'microblog', step-by-step, and I was trying to grasp the rationale behind DB migrations. I just discovered what is happening. See my answer :). Thx!